# How to set a permanent value to a Django Form Field

Tags: python, django, forms, field

I am building blogsite where authenticated user can add post. The form has three fields including 'user' field (which shows all the user list with a drop down option). The problem is authenticated user can also see other user name.

I have tried two solution

1. Exclude this field when rendering in template or
2. whatever the username is chosen the post post will be saved by the name of authenticated user

but the solution I want

'user' field will only show the name of the authenticated user and that will be submitted with title and description

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):

class Meta:
    model = Blog
   
    fields = '__all__'


view function

if fm.is_valid():
    us = fm.cleaned_data['user']
    ti = fm.cleaned_data['title']
    ds = fm.cleaned_data['desc']
    post = Blog(user=us, title=ti, desc=ds)
    messages.success(request, 'Blog Created')
    post.save()
```

{% csrf_token %}

```
{{form.user.label}}{{form.user}}<br><br>
```

{{form.title.label}}{{form.title}}
{{form.desc.label}}   {{form.desc}}

Comment: Share your template

Answer (score 0):

In your Form class

```
def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
    super(YourForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)
    self.fields['user'].disabled = True
```

initialise your form:

```
data = {'user': request.user}
fm = YourForm(initial=data)
```

next:

```
if fm.is_valid():
    us = fm.cleaned_data['user']
    ti = fm.cleaned_data['title']
    ds = fm.cleaned_data['desc']
    post = Blog(user=us, title=ti, desc=ds)
    messages.success(request, 'Blog Created')
    post.save()
```

Your form will get the user from request, so you do not have any dependency for user from form.

Comment: Thanks...but what i want is to show all the form fields  'user', 'title','desc;  ... but the user field will have only the  authenticated username ... the solution you provided excluded the  user field form the form. anyway your answer  was helpful learning new thing...

Answer (score 0):

in model form only include "title" and "desc" field so template not render "user" field, we can set user in views.py via dynamically

```
class BlogForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
        model = Blog
        fields = ('title','desc',)
```

#views.py here we can set user via dynamically user=request.user

```
if fm.is_valid():
    ti = fm.cleaned_data['title']
    ds = fm.cleaned_data['desc']
    post = Blog(user=request.user, title=ti, desc=ds)
    messages.success(request, 'Blog Created')
    post.save()
```

Comment: Thanks...but what i want is to show all the form fields 'user', 'title','desc; ... but the user field will be populated only by  the authenticated username ... the solution you provided excluded the user field form the form.

Comment: please share your full html template code

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.user.label}}{{form.user}}<br><br>

{{form.title.label}}{{form.title}}<br><br>
 {{form.desc.label}}   {{form.desc}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add">

</form>
    <input type="submit" value="Add"> # I wanna retain the user field here but it will be populated only by the authenticated user name.. currently it shows all other usernames registered ...

Comment: <form action="" method="post">
    {% csrf_token %}

    {{form.user.label}}{{form.user}}<br><br>

{{form.title.label}}{{form.title}}<br><br>
 {{form.desc.label}}   {{form.desc}}
    <input type="submit" value="Add">

</form>

Comment: you want show in user dropdown only who user is authenticated otherwise user field hide, right?

Comment: i want to show only the authenticated username....one solution given above is making it disabled with the authenticated username....if you have any other...please.....